# Description of a discrete set including ranges

Tags: notation

If there is a discrete set, example {1,2,3,14,15,16,21,22} how to write this mathematically?

A mathematical equations should satisfy if sets varies too. Kindly help me out, thanks in advance.

In this set 1-3 is of continuous, 14-16 is continuous and final is 21-22. It forms three ranges can it be written in expression with some notations.

For example if 1-3 is alone present we can write it as simple as 1:3 but here there are several ranges that exists. How to give notation for this scenario?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. $\{1,2,3,14,15,16,21,22\}$ is already mathematical notation for the set containing the elements $1,2,3,14,15,16,21$ and $22$.

Comment: If there is no "law" describing the elements of the set, the only way is to list them, as you have done.

Comment: Your title is misleading. You are not dealing with a "random" set. On the opposite, it is structured by the fact that there are continuous ranges.

Comment: It totally depends on the sequence and on your judgement. If the sequence happens to have a shorter description that is also easy to understand, go for it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust the title appears to have been edited to that by someone who's not the OP -- the original title was not misleading

Comment: @postmortes: you are right, I didn't notice. The old title wasn't much explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you already have is fine, and for small sets would be entirely normal.  You can also, in this case, write it as a union of integer intervals.  We can write $[m\ldots n]$ to denote $[m,n]\cap {\mathbb Z}$, i.e it is the set of all numbers between $n$ and $m$ inclusive that are integers.  So as an example, $[2\ldots5] = \{2,3,4,5 \}$.  Then your set becomes
$$ [1\ldots 3] \cup [14\ldots 16] \cup [21\dots 22]$$

Comment: $\left([1,3] \cup [14, 16] \cup [21, 22]\right) \cap \mathbb Z$ works in a similar way